# Android notification with sound & vibration, context issue?

Tags: android, audio, notifications, vibration

I'm trying to make a notification with custom sound and vibration.

```
Notification.Builder nb = new Notification.Builder(context)
.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.tickerHdr))
.setContentText(context.getString(R.string.tickerInfo))
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alarm)
.setAutoCancel(true)
.setWhen((new Date()).getTime());

if (isAlarm) {
    nb.setSound(Uri.parse(sirenSoundPath));
    nb.setVibrate(vibratePattern);
    nb.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
}       

Notification notification = nb.build();
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(ns);
mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFIC_ID, notification);
```

This works as expected when I call it from an activity. However, I need to call this when a SMS has been received even if my app has not been started. So I have extended BroadcastReceiver and overrides onReceive(Context context, Intent intent). When I create the notification from there it shows as expected, but without the custom sound and vibration. Maybe because I'm using the context received in onReceive? Or perhaps this will conflict with the sound and vibration the standard sms app causes when the sms is received? Any suggestions?

I know that I can play sound and vibrate directly like:

```
((Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(500);
```

But I would like to use the notification stuff so I can get the standard behaviour, e.g. cancel sound when notification is tapped.

(What I'm trying to do is to receive SMS messages from my home alarm and if it tells me that my house is on fire I would like my phone to make some extra noise so I don't read it three hours later.)

Comment: There's no problem using that Context to create a Notification. I would bet that yours, as you guessed, is being trumped by the SMS app's Notification. One solution might be to just delay your Notification for a few seconds.

Comment: I tried a small delay and it seems to work fine.